# Building scalable tcp server in node js

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, tcp, dependency-injection

So I'm not sure my title is the most accurate but I tried to give the best explenation I could.

I was recently at a job interview where I was asked this question(More or less as I don't remember the full question. This is the out of the top of my head):

> You need to make a simple tcp server that can be accessed through puTTy (or any other client for that matter).
>
> Once you are in, you need to write:
>
> login < username > (Doesn't matter what username).
>
> once you are logged in you have 3 operations you can do:
>
> - showDevices - will return a list of devices (Currently we have lamp and an airconditioner) - we can write mock objects. Let's assume they have a number Id.
> - Switch < deviceId > < on|off > - sets the device on or off.
> - SetValue < deviceId > < double > - set's the device's ranged value (Air condition tempature)
>
> Important things:
>
> - Separation - Separate the logic and communication layer. We work with a telenat server now but we will want to switch to an http server in the future. The process should be easy.
> - Extensibility- We currently have 4 operations (login, showDevices, Switch, SetValue) - write the server so it would be very easy for other programmers to add another operation. The code should be self-explanatory

The assignment could have been written in any language. I tried writing it in C# until I was stuck and couldn't continue. Lately I'm more into Node js and decided to give this another go... so I'm asking you guys for some helpful directons to this solution.

- How do I best seperate between the communication and the logic layer?
- Is there some sort of design pattern I should implement for  adding commands easier? (I looked at the command design pattern and I couldn't figuere out if it was meant for this kind of situation)
- Anything that can actually directs me in the right track (without telling me exactly what to do) will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I really like this challenge, I may have to steal it for my own technical interviews. :)

I think (without digging into writing code since you asked me not to), the way I'd approach it in Node is similar to the `commander.js` module.

So, a module that handles the socket stuff, probably just a server.js file that allows the connection, and then requires the module that exposes the available commands.

The available commands would just be (depending on how you want to allow upgrades) either all modules in a given directory (like commander.js does it) or all modules prefixed by a certain keyword (like grunt does it).

You can require all files in a directory with the `require-directory` module if you don't want to do it yourself, and then access each command by array-access notation.

Let me know if that's too high level, but that's the general approach I'd take in Node.

In C# it'd be a bit harder, you'd need to rely on reflection to allow for the addition of new plugins at runtime, or else use a DI container for finding them at compile time.

Comment: I wasn't aware of commander.js up until now. It seems like it could solve my problem in a breeze! I'll look more into it (Although I'm skeptical using commander.js in my solution is something the recruiter would have like me to do, perhaps digging into the implemenation of the module can help me with everything I need)

Comment: Depends on who's hiring. I can tell you that when I interview folks, I give the most points to people who both choose to use a 3rd party library that's appropriate, as well as who can explain what the library does, what the risks of using it are, etc.

Comment: I'll give it a go in a day or two. I might need further help if your answer is actually too high level. In that case some code would be helpful :)